# Changing the contentURL of a panel based on the actions on the current page rendered on panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using Erik Vold's toolbar button. I have a panel anchored to it. When one of the links is clicked on the html static page rendered in the panel, I need to display something else in the same panel.

I am trying to use port API for message passing between addon-code and the html static page. On listening a certain event, I want to change the contentURL field of the panel:

```
var myScript = "window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {" +
           "  var t = event.target;" +
           "  if (t.nodeName == 'A')" +
           "    self.port.emit('click-link', t.id);" +
           "}, false);"

var mainPanel = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  contentURL: require("self").data.url("appList.html"),
  contentScript: myScript
});

mainPanel.port.on("click-link", function(appName) {
  if(appName=='app1'){
  //mainPanel.resize(700,500);  --works
    mainPanel.contentURL="http://www.some-server/app1.html";  --fails
  }
  if(appName=='app2')
    ...
});
```

mainPanel.resize() works fine for resizing the panel. Is there a similar way to change contentURL for a Panel?

Comment: If you use the href attribute you will be redirect on the correct page.

Comment: Looking at the SDK code, changing `panel.contentURL` is supposed to be working. If it doesn't then maybe you found an SDK bug.

Comment: @WladimirPalant The example mentioned in the documentation does so from two different widgets. I am setting the contentURL property directly(not from a widget or a toolbarbutton). Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work, you found a bug in the panel module.  yay!

I filed [bug 795490](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795490) for you and there's a [pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/pull/594) with a fix that might take a little time to land but a fix should be coming.

Comment: The fix landed!  You should be able to get the latest version of the sdk with it in there. https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/commit/41d3fd8903dc290471b05c6e28191d33bce4b46c